# SIP-WebRTC gateway/bridge: Kurento OR openwebrtc OR Intel CS for webrtc

Tags: webrtc, sip, kurento, openwebrtc

I am researching implementation of a WebRTC-SIP gateway/bridge. That is, for example, to make a WebRTC call to a SIP end point via a SIP server like Asterisk. I know that Asterisk already supports this but I need an intermediary server for various needs like logging, recording, integration with local auth/signalling and other app modules. I looked at [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/), [Openwebrtc](http://www.openwebrtc.org/) (Ericson) and the lesser known Intel's [Collaboration Suite for WebRTC](https://software.intel.com/en-us/webrtc-sdk).

I need a server-side solution to interact with my Node Application server. Specifically, the server-API should be able to generate a SDP for a RTP end point and convert WebRTC SDP to the more generic SDP used by Legacy SIP servers or have a way to bridge these two end-points. I feel comfortable that this is possible with Kurento (saw a post on  except that I am not aware of any jsSip/sipML5 kind of API for Kurento. Kurento itself is not meant to provide signalling. For e.g., if the SDP generated by Kurento for the rtpEndpoint in Kurento has to be used in a SIP call/INVITE, how would one  implement it? For that matter, how would one initiate a SIP INVITE, for example, from Kurento? Are there third-party modules to do this?

Has anyone used the any of the servers listed above for a similar use case?

This is a programming question. I am looking for server APIs to implement a WebRTC to SIP gateway/bridge for media transcoding (if required), SDP transformation and SIP signalling.

Comment: Kurento has been used as a RTP to WebRTC gateway, using SIP as signaling protocol successfully

Comment: @igracia  Can you list, broadly speaking, the steps involved and do so as an ANSWER? I would think that it would require the node.js http-app server to have jssip-like module and Kurento client library integrated. We use socket.io for webRTC signalling messages(SDP, for instance). Would certainly like to accept that answer and it would be useful to MANY.

Comment: That's not something you can explain in one SO answer ;-) We'll try and create a post about that when we can.